# What does "..." mean in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java array argument “declaration” syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211099/java-array-argument-declaration-syntax)

I have seen `...` to be used in between of object type and object name in java. I get the idea that it represents collection of the object. Note the following examples:

```
public setMembers(Member... members);
Map map = ...;
```

My question is what "..." really means? I have never seen this in any documentation where they explained it.