# What does "..." mean in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “…” mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618930/what-does-mean-in-java)

Ok i was adapting a lib at work when i found this:

```
public void requireParameters(String... names){
        super.requireParameters(names);}
```

Sorry about my ignorance but what this means ?

thanks for your time