# What does a ... do as a parameter of a java function?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Java array argument “declaration” syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211099/java-array-argument-declaration-syntax)
>   [What is the ellipsis for in this method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)

I've stumbled upon a function that has a String... strings as a parameter. What is the significance of this? I'm assuming it means any number of string arguments but isn't that the point of List?

```
function doStuff(String... strings) {
    //Code
}
```

I'd appreciate an explanation of its purpose and usage in applications. Thanks

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504260/what-does-mean-in-java) question or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618930/what-does-mean-in-java) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211099/java-array-argument-declaration-syntax)

Comment: This question was just asked earlier today *and* closed as a duplicate.

Comment: There is no keyword 'function' in Java. Do you mean 'public [static] [void|int|String|Object|...]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I is the syntax for specifying [**varargs**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) i.e. specifying that a method can take a variable number of arguments.

> *The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that **the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments**. Varargs can be used only in the final argument position.*

Answer (score 0):

It's the Ellipsis. It allows varargs, see:

[What is the ellipsis (...) for in this method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)