# Java can't find method main

Tags: java

Im having trouble with a simple hello world program lol! Im hoping someone can shed some light on this.

So the error im receiving is the following:

```
$ javac Hello.java
$ java Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

So by the error, I can see that it's *obviously* missing main, but it's there:

```
class Hello
{
  public static void main(String argv)
  {
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```

I'm on Mac OS/X if it's any help.

Comment: String[] argv and not String argv

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem is that your method does not take String array as a argument. Use following signature instead:

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
```

or

```
public static void main(String argv[])
```

Other valid option is:

```
public static void main(String ... argv)
```

In Java Language Specification this is told as follows:

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must
>   specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of
>   String.

Comment: You do not have to give it any actual arguments when starting JVM. In such a case main method will receive empty array.

Comment: Just a side question; Im still receiving the error by removing the args part to just this: `public static void main()`

Comment: That's how it is, main simply needs to have array as an argument. But you do not have to give arguments when you execute it with 'java Hello'.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot about `[]` in `String[] argv` or `...` in `String... argv`. This array is used to store arguments used in command creating JVM for your class like

```
java Hello argument0 argument1 argument2`
```

and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Main method has signature that accepts `String[]` and you wrote `String` which is wrong,

Make it

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
```

or [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618930/what-does-mean-in-java/4618944#4618944)

```
public static void main(String... argv)
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to put the array syntax,
You can even use varargs as per JAVA 1.5

```
public static void main(String... argv)
```

Answer (score 2):

problem is with `main` signature, which should be

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
```

or could be

```
public static void main(String ... argv) // known as varargs
```

instead of `public static void main(String argv)` which is in your case

have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN)

for varargs [look](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
public static void main(String... args)
public static void main(String args[])
```

Java programs start executing at the main method, which has the above method prototype

Answer (score 1):

Your main method signature is wrong `String` instead of `String []`

use

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
```

or

```
public static void main(String... argv)
```

read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)