# Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]

Tags: java

I'm learning, I'm newbie
but I wanted to know what I do to get "run" it.
this happening a error:

```
Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].
```

This is the code:

```
/**
 * @author "LionH"
 */
public class Caneirinho {

    public static void contar() {
        int i = 1;
        String a = " Carneirinho",
            b = " pulando a cerca.",
            c = "s";

        for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                System.out.println(i + a + b);
            } else {     
                System.out.println(i + a + c + b);
            }
        }
    }
} // Carneirinho
```

Comment: What part of that exceptionally clear error message don't you understand?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11720463/1393766) you have few examples of correct main method signature.

Answer (score 6):

Any Java class that you run directly must have a `main` method, which is the entry point, i.e., where the program starts when you execute the code.

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Just rename your method `contar()` to `main(String args[])` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks already managed to fix the error, excuse the stupid question, but as I said I'm learning,
one more doubt:
as increasing the time interval?

Sorry for my english, I'm learning too
and once again thank you!

Comment: Time interval of what?  How long between each iteration of the `for` loop?  Does the content scroll by too fast and you want to see it all or something?

Answer (score 3):

Alternate to @mellamokb Answer

```
public class Caneirinho{

 public static void contar(){
   int i = 1;
   String a = " Carneirinho",
     b = " pulando a cerca.",
     c = "s";

   for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
     if(i==1){
       System.out.println( i + a + b );
      } else {     
        System.out.println( i + a + c + b ); 
        Thread.sleep(1000);  // thread wais for 1 sec ie 1000 milisecond    
      }     
    }
  }

public static void main(String[] args){
   contar(); // call contar() from main method
}

}//Carneirinho
```

Comment: Thanks already managed to fix the error, excuse the stupid question, but as I said I'm learning,
one more doubt:
as increasing the time interval?

Sorry for my english, I'm learning too
and once again thank you!

Comment: @user2034259 What do you mean by --->  `one more doubt: as increasing the time interval?`

Comment: more time between one and the next.

Comment: @Falmer I still unable to understand your question! :-(

Comment: @Falmer Do you mean to say what time difference it will make if you apply my answer and mellamokb answer? Am I correct predicting your question?

Comment: no, i want to know how do I make for my "program" have a greater time difference, when you press "Run".

Comment: @Falmer I updated the answer. You can make use of `Thread.sleep()` if you want some time delay between printing the values. `Thread` is kinda complex and vast area. However it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a java program, it can have a number of classes but for all the classes to run we should have a main class which is used to implement the classes which we defined. You created a class without main in it. The program will start its execution from main.