# Regarding Variable Arguments and Anonymous array

Tags: java

Please advise How can I convert the below program into variable arguments that is the new feature introduced by java 5, rite now I am making use of anonymous inner arrays ..

```
public class AnnonymousArrayExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //calling method with anonymous array argument
        System.out.println("first total of numbers: " + sum(new int[]{ 1, 2,3,4}));
        System.out.println("second total of numbers: " + sum(new int[]{ 1, 2,3,4,5,6,}));

    }

    //method which takes an array as argument
    public static int sum(int[] numbers){
        int total = 0;
        for(int i: numbers){
            total = total + i;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your method signature like this
`public static int sum(int ... numbers)`

The following are valid invocations

```
sum();
sum(1,2,3);
sum(1,2,3,4,5);
sum(new int[] {1,2,3})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use var-args

```
public static int sum(int... numbers){}
```

---

**Also See**

- [What does "..." mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618930/what-does-mean-in-java/4618944#4618944)

Comment: what change need to be done in calling part also please advise.!

Comment: You can call it like sum(1,2,3,4); // any number of argument

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as an "anonymous inner array" - what you've got there is simply an [array creation expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10).

To use varargs arrays, you just change the method declaration like this:

```
public static int sum(int... numbers) {
    // Code as before - the type of numbers will still be int[]
}
```

And change the calling code to:

```
System.out.println("first total of numbers: " + sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

See [section 8.4.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) for more details, or the [Java 1.5 language guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 0):

to use `varargs (...)` change you method signature `public static int sum(int... numbers)`.

```
public static int sum(int... numbers){
       int total = 0;
       for(int i: numbers){
           total = total + i;
       }
       return total;
}
```

...

```
System.out.println("first total of numbers: " + sum(new int[]{ 1, 2,3,4}));
System.out.println("second total of numbers: " + sum(new int[]{ 1, 2,3,4,5,6,}));
```

More on `varargs` - [Reference Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your parameter declaration (from [] to ...) and no change in calling part :

```
public class AnnonymousArrayExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // calling method with anonymous array argument
        System.out.println("first total of numbers: "
                + sum(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }));
        System.out.println("second total of numbers: "
                + sum(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, }));

    }

    // method which takes an array as argument
    public static int sum(int... numbers) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i : numbers) {
            total = total + i;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum method should be declared as follows:

```
public static int sum(int ... numbers)
```

And the call should look like:

```
sum(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **sum** function would look like this:

```
public static int sum(int... numbers) {
  int total = 0;
  for (int i : numbers) {
    total = total + i;
  }
  return total;
}
```

It looks almost indentical to your original code - and for good reason. As far as I know, internally, the varargs are translated by the compiler using arrays. The signatures of both functions are identical - you would not be able to keep both in the code. So the "ellipsis" syntax is just syntactic sugar.

And the invocation of the function:

```
int total = sum(1,2,3,4);
```

Looks cleaner syntactically, but under the hood, it is the same as your original code - the compiler will create an array, initialize it with the given values and pass it to the function as parameter.