# Java method to sum any number of ints

Tags: java, sum

I need to write a java method `sumAll()` which takes any number of integers and returns their sum.

```
sumAll(1,2,3) returns 6
sumAll() returns 0
sumAll(20) returns 20
```

I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need:

```
public int sumAll(int...numbers){

    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        result += numbers[i];
    } 
    return result;
}
```

Then call the method and give it as many int values as you need:

```
int result = sumAll(1,4,6,3,5,393,4,5);//.....
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to use public static int sumAll

Comment: Can we do this in less than O(n) time?

Answer (score 20):

If your using Java8 you can use the **IntStream**:

```
int[] listOfNumbers = {5,4,13,7,7,8,9,10,5,92,11,3,4,2,1};
System.out.println(IntStream.of(listOfNumbers).sum());
```

> Results: **181**

Just 1 line of code which will sum the array.

Answer (score 9):

```
public int sumAll(int... nums) { //var-args to let the caller pass an arbitrary number of int
    int sum = 0; //start with 0
    for(int n : nums) { //this won't execute if no argument is passed
        sum += n; // this will repeat for all the arguments
    }
    return sum; //return the sum
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am more comfortable with the other notation for for loops

Answer (score 2):

Use [var args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618930/what-does-mean-in-java/4618944#4618944)

```
public long sum(int... numbers){
      if(numbers == null){ return 0L;}
      long result = 0L;
      for(int number: numbers){
         result += number;
      }
      return result;   
}
```

Comment: So what if the sum overflows the integer value ;-)

Comment: result is of type long, OP can handle data type based on his/her case

Comment: Thank you. Return type had to be int. Does (int... numbers) notation work for other types such as long double and even String?

Comment: Yes it works, see the link in the answer for detailed description

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumAll {
    public static void sumAll(int arr[]) {//initialize method return sum
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum is : " + sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//create scanner object 
        System.out.print("How many # you want to add : ");
        num = input.nextInt();//return num from keyboard
        int[] arr2 = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Num" + (i + 1) + ": ");
            arr2[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        sumAll(arr2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 System.out.println(SumofAll(12,13,14,15));//Insert your number here.
   {
      public static int SumofAll(int...sum)//Call this method in main method.
          int total=0;//Declare a variable which will hold the total value.
            for(int x:sum)
          {
           total+=sum;
           }
  return total;//And return the total variable.
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do, assuming you have an array with value and array length: `arrayVal[i]`, `arrayLength`:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    sum += arrayVal[i];
}

System.out.println("the sum is" + sum);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Consider adding the method signature to improve answer quality.

Comment: You do not need a variable for array length, you have this value in your array.