# Convert a C# method with "params" modifier to Java

Tags: c#, java, arrays, parameters, multidimensional-array

I have a C# method that use "params" modifier for a 2-dimentions array.

```
/// <summary>
///   Combine vectors horizontally.
/// </summary>
/// 
public static T[] Concatenate<T>(params T[][] vectors)
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i++)
        size += vectors[i].Length;

    T[] r = new T[size];

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < vectors[i].Length; j++)
            r[c++] = vectors[i][j];

    return r;
}
```

I convert it to Java like this:

```
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectors.length; i++)
    {
        size += vectors[i].;
    }

    T[] r =(T[]) Array.newInstance(vectors[0][0].getClass(), size);

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectors.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vectors[i].length; j++)
        {
                r[c++] = vectors[i][j];
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

But it seems to be wrong. Solution doesn't work.
Please someone tell me the right way.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you have a syntax error on line 4 in your java code. Furthermore, its imcomplete, where is the method declaration? What does "doesn't work" mean? What do you expect to happen, what does happen?

Comment: If vectors is of size 0 or vectors[0] if of size 0, your Java code won't work.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362). Please explain the requirements in plain English, not in code in another programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you use `...` instead of `params`, as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211099/how-does-the-java-array-argument-declaration-syntax-work)

So you declare your method like this (note the loss of one []):

```
public static T[] Concatenate<T>(T[]...vectors)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- Just avoid using arrays and generics together. Thanks to type earasure, they don't play well together. (You don't have that problem on CLR.)
- Prefer existing solutions. Guava's [`Iterables.concat`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable...%29) appears to fit the bill here.