# AsyncTask methods: I get error whether I write "@Override" annotation or not

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, annotations, overriding

I am writing an Android client for consuming a SOAP based web service. I am using an `AsyncTask` for performing the networking (that is calling the webservice) operation. I am in the middle of writing the client.

1. Now as I try to implement the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` method,
   I get the following two errors at `protected String
   doInBackground(String[] params)...` *if I write* the `@Override`
   annotation with it:

   **The method doInBackground(String[]) of type MainActivity.MyTask must override or implement a supertype method. 1 Quick fix: Remove
   '@Override' annotation**

   and the following error at `private class MyTask extends
   AsyncTask...` :

   **The type MainActivity.MyTask must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask.doInBackground(String[]...).
   2 Quick fixes: Add unimplemented methods** (this auto-generates the
   `doInBackground` method again *with the `@Override`
   annotation*)**.** **Make type 'MyTask' abstract.**
2. *if I don't write* the `@Override` annotation, I get only the second error.

   ```
   ...
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           String [] params = {URL, METHOD_NAME, NAMESPACE}; 
       }

       private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String> {

           //@Override write it or not write it? :s ****************
           protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return null;
           }
       }
   ...
   ```

What might be the reason behind this? What should I do?

Comment: Change `private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String>` to `private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` and write `String...` instead of `String[]` in `doInBackground argments`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have syntax error:

Change

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String>
```

to

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

and write `String...` instead of `String[]` in `doInBackground` arguments.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @BlazeTama Its converted to String[] at last.. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4211138/1777090)

Answer (score 2):

Since the method in `AsyncTask<String[], Void, String>` is declared as `doInBackground(String[]... params)` - possibly after substituting in the right type parameter, you need to have the same parameter types when you overrride it in `MyTask`.  It looks like you've written `doInBackground(String[] params)` instead of `doInBackground(String[]... params)`.

Note that that would mean that `params` would be a whole sequence of arrays of Strings.  That may not be what you want.  Did you really mean for `MyTask` to extend `AsyncTask<String[], Void, String>`?

Comment: Oh my bad, it should rather have been a varargs `doInBackground(String... params)`, I believe because the `AsyncTask` class itself which is the super type must be having a vararg argument in its `doInBackground`. Doesn't matter in my program even though I am passing a String array, because varargs are treated just like arrays I believe. Thank you, this solves my problem.

Comment: If you want to pass `String... params` here, then you probably want to change `MyTask` so that it extends `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` as given in MysticMagic's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The doInBackground method should be written as

```
doInBackground(Params... params)
```

Comment: How will that help, when the compile error states that the class has to implement `AsyncTask.doInBackground(String[]...)`?

Comment: Params being meant as a general placeholder here, not that he should write that explicitly instead of String[]... I should have been clearer