# android: calling Google API .getPlaceById with multiple place_id's

Tags: android, google-places-api

In order to reduce the number of API calls, I'm trying to query place details by passing several place_ids at a time (up to 10).  I haven't found any useful information beyond the docs.

[https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html#getPlaceById(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, java.lang.String...)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html#getPlaceById(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String...))

Notably, the constructor is:

`public abstract PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> getPlaceById (GoogleApiClient client, **String... placeIds**)`

and the doc says:  Returns Place objects for each of the given place IDs.

I don't have any problem when passing a single `place_id`, but when I pass a comma delimted string of id's, all of which are known to be good, I get a `status = "SUCCESS"` but a buffer count of 0.

Does anyone know the correct way to pass multiple id's to `getPlaceById()`?

Here's my code if that helps at all:

```
    Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, searchIds)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                int cnt = places.getCount();
                if (places.getStatus().isSuccess() && places.getCount() > 0) {
                    for (int i=0; i < places.getCount(); i++) {
                        final Place myPlace = places.get(i);
                        Log.d("<< cache >> ", "Place found: " + myPlace.getName());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("<< cache >> ", "Place not found");
                }
                places.release();
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) argument. You call it like this:

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, 
        "placeId1", "placeId2", "placeId3");
```

More detail in this SO question: [How does the Java array argument declaration syntax "..." work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211099/how-does-the-java-array-argument-declaration-syntax-work)

Comment: I had read that posting, but I assumed it was equivalent to:

String ids = "placeid1, placeid2, placeid3".  

I didn't try this, but I probably will just to see if it works. 
String ids = "\"placeid1\",\"placeid2\""

The array is working well and doesn't have the messy escaped quotes, so I'll probably keep using that approach anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've read that String... can be passed as either a comma delimited string or a string array, for one reason or other, getPlaceById appears to require an array.  When I use this code to prepare the place id parameter, it works fine:

```
    String search[] = new String[idsToSearch.size()];
    search = idsToSearch.toArray(search);
```