# What does '...' mean in method parameter javadoc?

Tags: java

I'm looking at the Files class in java 7, and I see this method

```
copy(InputStream, Path, CopyOptions...)
```

How do I read "CopyOptions...". What's the ... mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211099/how-does-the-java-array-argument-declaration-syntax-work check that.

Comment: you missed the variable name after `...`. It is `copy(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options)`